# How to solve quadratic problem with logarithmic function?(In Matlab)

Tags: matlab, math, optimization, quadratic-programming

I want to get optimized `x1`, `x2` from the following equation:

[image: Formula to be minimized]

What makes it different from typical quadratic function is the `log2y`, which prevents me from using `quadprog` in Matlab. Is there any way in solving the quadratic function with log?

Comment: Is the pic cracked? Here is the formula: min y^T  Q y - φ b^T  log2y.

Comment: Use [fmincon](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html) or [fminunc](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fminunc.html) depending on whether you have constraints or not.